# Firefox ctrl+tab not behaving the same on same version Firefox but on different machines

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am using Firefox 35.0.1 on a Windows 7 64bit.

On my work computer I have the same Firefox version and operating system but whenever I do Ctrl+Tab on my work pc, I go to the previous accessed tab or if I hold it I see a little menu that shows the tabs.

On my home pc I get nothing of this.
The plugins I have one I have on the other but maybe I changed some setting.

Does anyone know how I can get Ctrl+Alt to go to the previous accessed tab and not just go to the tab that is next to the active tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-new-ctrltab-preview-thumbnails-list-in-mozilla-firefox-3-6-beta/

Don't know why this was set up in my work machine.